# how to turn try catch function into promise and use promise.all

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In Reactjs, I have two try-catch functions listed as below, and I need to wrap them into a promise.all function. Could anyone tell me how please? I know first I have to turn those two functions into promise, but how?

```
  function one(){
    let isValid = true;
    ...
    if(isValid){
      try{
       const response = await AA.sendMsg({XX})
       return response
       }catch(e){
        console.log(e)
        }
      }
    }
function two(){
    let isValid = true;
    ...
    if(isValid){
      try{
       const response = await BB.sendMsg({YY})
       return response
       }catch(e){
        console.log(e)
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: First you need both functions to be `async` to use `await` in them. And it will automagically make them return a promise. So you can do something like `Promise.all([one(), two()])`

Answer (score 1):

`sendMsg` **already returns a Promise** (at least, it should, if it doesn't then it makes no sense to use `await` or introduce Promises).

Wrapping then in extra Promises would be an anti-pattern. Don't do that.

Just pass them to Promise.all:

```
const [responseAA, responseBB] = await Promise.all([AA.sendMsg(...), BB.sendMsg(...)]);
```

Answer (score -1):

**await** is only available if you declare your function as **async**.

Given that, invoking them will give you a promise without extra work.

so just do:

```
const result = await Promise.all([one(), two()])
```